# Expand CSS grid cell

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

Here's what I have right now:

[image]

```css
.post {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.post div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
}
.post div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
}
.post div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <div class="post__id">
    <p>001</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__body">
    <a href="..."><p>Lorem ipsum</p></a>
    <p>text…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__date">
    <p>01.01.2021</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a good way to expand the cell in the middle to take up the maximum amount of space as it is the case with the cells below filled with text?

P.S.: One way to solve this:

```css
.post {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1000fr 1fr;
}
/* and comment out the rest of the above code */
```

But I don't think it's a good solution…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto`.

This seems a bit odd as `1fr` seems to be a somewhat fixed length and `auto` seems to represent a dynamic length. But check out the [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns#values) for [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)

> <flex>
>
> Is a non-negative dimension with the unit
> fr specifying the track's flex factor. Each <flex>-sized track
> takes a share of the remaining space in proportion to its flex factor.
>
> When appearing outside a minmax() notation, it implies an automatic
> minimum (i.e. minmax(auto, <flex>)).
>
> auto
>
> As a
> maximum represents the largest max-content size of the items in that
> track.
>
> As a minimum represents the largest minimum size of items in that
> track (specified by the min-width/min-height of the items). This is
> often, though not always, the min-content size.
>
> If used outside of minmax() notation, auto represents the range
> between the minimum and maximum described above. This behaves
> similarly to minmax(min-content,max-content) in most cases.

So `auto` is practically just `max-content` and `1fr` will take all the remaining space.

```css
.post {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
}

.post div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
}
.post div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
}
.post div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <div class="post__id">
    <p>001</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__body">
    <a href="..."><p>Lorem ipsum</p></a>
    <p>text…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__date">
    <p>01.01.2021</p>
  </div>
</div>
```